# Filling with z-axis when using splot

Tags: gnuplot

Is it possible to fill with the z instead of the x-axis when using splot?
When I use one of these options:

```
splot 'file.dat' using 2:(0):2 w filledcurves
splot 'file.dat' using 1:(0):2:(0) with pm3d
```

The filling is performed with respect to the x-axis. But it seems to be illegal to perform:

```
splot 'file.dat' using 2:(0):2 w filledcurves z
```

Is there another way to fill with the z-axis?

Comment: Have a loo at Christoph's answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550223/fill-area-below-a-line-in-3d-with-splot

Comment: @Miguel, thanks for the suggestion. I had seen this question already, but they are filling with respect to the x-axis. I would like to fill with respect to the z-axis.