# Fence plot in gnuplot - filling with filledcurve

Tags: plot, gnuplot

I created the following plot using a gnuplot input like this:

```
    splot "avt_list.dat" every ::0::120 u 1:2:3 w filledcurve lc rgb "red" ,\    
          "" every ::0::120 u 1:2:3 w l lc rgb "black" lw 2, \ [...]
```

[Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB03l.png)

The input data has the format

```
x1 y11 z11
x1 y12 z12
...
x2 y21 z21
x2 y22 z22
...
```

I'm not satisfied with this output since the areas under the curves aren't really filled and it doesn't look good. I tried to google a solution using this filledcurve keyword but I didn't find anything useful.
So what I'm basically looking for is either:

1. The area under a curve is completely filled with e.g. red, **or**
2. the area under a curve is just white but *not transparent*.

Does anybody have a (preferably simple) solution for this?

Thanks in advance and best regards!

Comment: `filledcurves` doesn't work with `splot`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/25550223 for a possible solution to get fence plots. Yes, this is quite hacky because gnuplot doesn't support fence plots out-of-the-box.