# How can you fill between a curve and anything other than zmin in an splot in gnuplot?

Tags: 3d, gnuplot, fill

I am looking to acceive creating a 3D plot similar to this:

```
         z ^  **
           |     *
           |       ***                   **
           |           *               *###*
           |             *           *######**  * ***
           |               *    ****###########*#####
           |               ###*######################
           ,-----------------------------------------> y
          /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /
         /---0---0---0---1---1---1---0---0---0---0    1
        /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /
       /---0---0---0---0---1---1---1---0---0---0    2
      /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /
     /---0---0---0---0---0---1---1---1---1---0    3
    /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /   /
   /---0---0---0---0---0---0---0---1---1---1    4
x v   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
```

I.e. a 3D plot of an `x`-`y`-dependent surface/contour plot of a function `g(x,y)` and a 2D function `f(y)` in the `y`-`z` plane which is filled if `g(x,y) > 0`...

My approach was using the filledcurves option in gnuplot, but I can't quite manage to get it right.

In a 2D plot what you can do is (e.g. with `f = sin(x)`, `g = -0.5`) this:

```
plot '+' u 1:(($1)>0?sin($1):-1/0) w filledcurves above y1=-0.5
```

resulting in: [image: 2D Version]
In the 3D plot however, when I try something similar:

```
xMIN = -1.5
xMAX = 0.5
yMIN = -0.5
yMAX = 1.5
zMIN = -4
zMAX = 8
set isosamples 100
set xyplane at 0
set xrange [xMIN:xMAX]
set yrange [yMIN:yMAX]
set zrange [zMIN:zMAX]
f(x) = 3*sin(3*x)+x**2
g(x,y) = -6*x**2 -12*y**2 - 8*x*y + 6*y+ 2
max(a,b) = a>b?a:1/0
set hidden
set view 45
splot max(g(x,y),0), \
      '++'   u 1:(1.5):(f($1)) w l, \
      ''   u 1:(1.5):(g(($1),($2)) > 0 ? f($1) : -1/0) w filledcurves
```

results in:

[image: 3D Version]

This is almost what I want, but the filling is always done until zMIN, but I would like to specify e.g. that it shades until 0 or a curve:
  Adding `above y1=0` after the last line gives me:

```
      "3D.gpl", line 22: unexpected or unrecognized token
```

Also, specifying a fourth datafield like

```
      ...:(-0) w filledcurves
```

as would work in the 2D case, just changes the color here, so setting a second curve until which to fill does not seem possible...

I did see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25550223/fill-area-below-a-line-in-3d-with-splot) question as well as [this](http://www.gnuplotting.org/splot-filledcurves/) blog post on gnuplotting, but both answers and the post seem to have the same issue: They are all filling until zmin by default.

What I did manage to acceive after some tinkering is this:

[image]

Here I am using the fact that there are points in the domain for which `g(x,y\') > 0` and others `g(x,y\'\') ≤ 0` for any `x`.
This results in a very hacky solution, but:

1. To make it dense enough, you have to modify the sampling rate, affecting the surface plot of g as well... In fact simply setting a really high sampling rate appears to crash the splot entirely and I will only see part of it!
2. Since the 'filling' now effectively is a surface plot squished into a 2D plane you see it's bottom in a different color, of course you can prevent this by setting `set hidden3d offset 0` but than this option is global and holds for any other surface where you might not actually want it...

It would be interesting to see if there's a more rigorous solution!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replacing the last line of your gnuplot script with

```
  ''   u 1:(1.5):(g(($1),($2)) > 0 ? f($1) : -1/0) w impulse lw 5
```

gives the following. Does that help?

[image]

Comment: That is a good first step, but I believe this still only allows the 'filling' to be done until a fixed axis, in this case `z=0`. Since for my own purposes this solution works fair enough, I accept this answer, However, it would be nice to know if there are alternatives that fillbetween two arbitrary curves with identical parametrizations or similar.